# проблемы с биндингом события tkinter "<Configure>"

Tags: python, tkinter, события

```
from tkinter.font import Font
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')
root['bg']='black'
def config(a):
    font['size']=-round(a.width*0.6/11) #len(lab['text'])=11
    print(a.width)
    lab['font']=font
font=Font(family='Droid Serif',size=-11,root=root.master)
lab=Label(root,text='get bigger!'.upper(),font=font,bg='black',fg='white')
lab.place(relx=0.2,relwidth=0.6,rely=0.45)
root.bind('<Configure>',config)
root.mainloop()
```

В итоге на outputе сразу,в начале программы,появляется:

```
200
120
120
```

Окно я никак не трогал и не конфигурировал,но bind почему-то срабатывает,и шрифт в начале,естественно,получается меньше,чем должен быть

Comment: а 5я строчка у вас работает ? вроде нужно писать иначе root.configure(background='black'). иии что за событие вы отлавливаете ?

Comment: 1.Работает,выражения root['bg']='black' и root.config(bg='black') эквивалентны,только первым способом быстрее пишется.

Comment: 2.Изменение размеров окна,событие также реагирует на изменение местоположения окна,но это ничего не меняет

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашёл,заметив,что 120/200=0.6,то есть отношение длины lab к длине root,оказалось,что событие реагирует не только на root,но и на все его дочерние виджеты

```
def config(a):
    if a.widget.__class__==Tk:
        font['size']=-round(a.width*0.6/11) #len(lab['text'])=11
        lab['font']=font
```

Теперь всё работает

Comment: Также можно проверять не класс виджета, а сам виджет: `if a.widget == root:` Суть та же, но ИМХО выглядит более красиво.

Comment: Ваш вариант также технически лучше,потому что мой вариант не даст отличить два объекта Label(например,я хочу,чтобы событие активировалось только при изменении одной метки),а вариант с сравнением непосредственно объектов,а не их классов,такую возможность даёт.